# Material Table - Editable Cell Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am using Material Table to display table data. I want to apply validation on surname field. If `surname` length is less than 3, it should show **too small** error in red below the input field.

How can this be achieved? The sample code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-breeze-corjj?file=/src/App.tsx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `editable` option to check the `validation`. Here I am using `onRowUpdate` to check the updated data so that we can show the validation message. You can check [full example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialtabledemo-validation-error-example-ew9rd)

```
<MaterialTable
            title="Editable Example"
            columns={
                [
                    {
                        title: 'Name', field: 'name',
                        editComponent: (props) => (
                            <TextField
                                type="text"
                                error={nameError.error}
                                helperText={nameError.helperText}
                                value={props.value ? props.value : ''}
                                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        )
                    },
                    { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' }
                ]}
            data={state.data}
            icons={tableIcons}
            editable={{
                onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {

                            if (newData.name === '' || newData.name.length < 3) {
                                setNameError({
                                    error: true,
                                    label: 'required',
                                    helperText: 'Name should be more than 3 character'
                                });
                                reject();
                                return;
                            }

                            resolve();
                            if (oldData) {
                                setState(prevState => {
                                    const data = [...prevState.data];
                                    data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                    return { ...prevState, data };
                                });
                            }
                        }, 600);
                    })
            }}
        />
```

Comment: Thank you but I want the functionality that when a user click on the cell, it should become editable

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
      title: "Surname",
      field: "surname",
      editComponent: (props: any) => (
        <TextField
          onChange={props.onChange}
          type="number"
          helperText={props.helperText}
          error={props.error}
          variant="standard"
          value={props.value}
        />
      ),
      validate: (rowData: any) =>
        rowData.surname.length < 3
          ? { isValid: false, helperText: "too small" }
          : true
    }
```

maybe this might help, I think. Try using `column.editComponent` to override edit component for a column and then using props pass the `helperText` and `error` to the `TextField`. I have used the `material-ui v5` `TextField` here
.